# How can I prevent previously deployed artifacts from being overwritten?

Tags: maven, maven-3, artifactory

We use Artifactory for our company's Maven repository.  Is there a way to set it up (or set Maven up) so that an artifact can't be deployed to the repository if there is a pre-existing artifact with the same version number?

The reasoning for this is to make sure that valid releases don't accidentally get overwritten.  If an artifact really does need to be re-deployed, one of our developers can use the Artifactory web interface to delete it.  Then they can deploy the new copy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is easily achieved by revoking the "Delete" permission from the deploying users\groups on the target repository; the delete permission is required for both artifact removal and artifact re-deployment.

All user\group permissions are editable within the UI at *Admin->Security->Permissions*.
Also see [Managing Permissions](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Permissions)

Comment: Worked for me. Be sure to check that anonymous user are not allowed to deploy.

Comment: Having a play and I have a `deployers` group which only has the `Deploy/Cache` permission granted but I am seeing no failure when trying to overwrite an artifact...

Comment: I see the same behavior as Dori - revoking the 'Delete/Overwrite' permission successfully blocks artifact deletion, but does not prevent overwriting artifacts.

Comment: The `Deploy` permission allows overwriting SNAPSHOT's but not other versions.