# Artifactory: Avoid overwriting already existing release package?

Tags: locking, package, release, overwrite, artifactory

is it possible to avoid overwriting (lock) an existing release package in Artifactory? We have already backups, but it is complicated to restore all release packages, that belongs to a specific release version. We want to avoid an release replace.

Thx

Comment: Answer is here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461152/how-can-i-prevent-previously-deployed-artifacts-from-being-overwritten

Comment: answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461152

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent previously deployed artifacts from being overwritten?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461152/how-can-i-prevent-previously-deployed-artifacts-from-being-overwritten)