# Deploying Jar with same version

Tags: maven, maven-3, artifactory, jfrog-mission-control

Can anyone provide me a solution for not allowing jar with the same version to be pushed on repository again?

I am using **JFrog** as artifactory. And Maven version is **3.0.5**

Comment: First. What you have tried so far? and what do you mean by `same version`? Are we talking about a SNAPSHOT or a release version?

Comment: The same version means one project to be deployed on artifactory with the existing version.

Comment: So we are talking about a release version like `1.0.0`...if so it could be configured (If i'm not mistaken) but I can strongly discourage it cause releases must be immutable...otherwise you will ran into other issues...

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461152/how-can-i-prevent-previously-deployed-artifacts-from-being-overwritten

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent previously deployed artifacts from being overwritten?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461152/how-can-i-prevent-previously-deployed-artifacts-from-being-overwritten)

Comment: One more Question, Need to restrict all project except one from being overridden. How can I achieve this?