# How to avoid overriding the existing files while uploading to Artifactory using JFrog rt CLI

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli

I am uploading the files to Artifactory server using JFrog CLI using spec file (jfrog rt). I do not see any option to avoid overriding the existing files in Artifactory server while uploading using [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory).

Does anybody know any work around or any other option to avoid overriding.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the reason you want the files not to be overridden? Is it performance or logical issue?

Comment: Answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461152/how-can-i-prevent-previously-deployed-artifacts-from-being-overwritten

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent previously deployed artifacts from being overwritten?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461152/how-can-i-prevent-previously-deployed-artifacts-from-being-overwritten)