# immutable artifactory PyPI: prevent re-uploads and deletes

Tags: artifactory

Currently I have a problem where if a package is accidentally re-uploaded at the same version the hashes change, and so packages pinned with `--generate-hashes` will fail to install.

Is there a way to prevent re-uploads to the same version, just like pypi.org?
Also a way to prevent deletes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent previously deployed artifacts from being overwritten?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461152/how-can-i-prevent-previously-deployed-artifacts-from-being-overwritten)

Comment: Sounds like [this plugin](https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/tree/master/storage/restrictOverwrite) might be helpful.