# Blocking artifact overwriting at repo level

Tags: maven, artifactory, artifact

I am trying to block overwriting in JFrog Artifactory. I have a two Maven repos: one for snapshot versions and another for releases, the first one should allow overwriting while the second one doesn't. As I can see it must be configured at user level ([How can I prevent previously deployed artifacts from being overwritten?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461152/how-can-i-prevent-previously-deployed-artifacts-from-being-overwritten)) but I would need to do it at repo level. Is there any way to do it? Maybe it is possible configuring Maven?

Comment: Just a comment: Usually, individual developers should not upload artifacts to Artifactory. The upload should be done from a build server (like Jenkins, Gitlab CI, ...), and then, you usually just need one technical user.

Comment: @JFabianMeier that's exactly how we do it, using Jenkins and Maven we publish the artifacts in Artifactory

Comment: So why not just configure the non-overwriting at user level? If you Jenkins user cannot override, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've implemented the solution based in user permissions. It seems to be the only way of doing it and works for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to use [Include and Exclude Patterns](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Management#RepositoryManagement-CommonSettings) at the repo level.

The Include Patterns and the Exclude Patterns fields provide a way to filter out specific repositories when trying to resolve the location of different artifacts.

In each field you can specify a list of Ant-like patterns to filter in and filter out artifact queries. Filtering works by subtracting the excluded patterns (default is none) from the included patterns (default is all).

Comment: How can it help me to prevent overwriting? I mean the path can be known, but the version is only known at the time the artifact is published